# simple sql column not found

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

What am I doing wrong in this sql:

```
Update products 
Set products.products_status = 0
Where products.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id And
products_to_categories.categories_id = 114
```

The error I am getting is: #1054 - Unknown column 'products_to_categories.products_id' in 'where clause' but that column does exist and I checked the spelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the reason for that is you didn't specify the table `products_to_categories` on the `UPDATE` statement. You can join the table even with `update` statement though, try,

```
Update  products a
        INNER JOIN products_to_categories b
            ON a.products_id = b.products_id
Set a.products_status = 0
Where b.categories_id = 114
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned the table `products_to_categories` before in the query, so all the columns in it are unknown.

You need to add a FROM clause or something similar; the detailed notation depends on the DBMS you're using, which was not specified when I first answered.

The DBMS has been identified as MySQL (based on the error number), so the correct syntax in MySQL is described in the manual for the [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) statement.  It doesn't use a FROM clause (other DBMS do, though).  See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732435/15168) by [JW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491243/jw).

Comment: @JW: thanks for the reassurance...you obviously recognize the error number, which I don't, which allows you to specify the DBMS.

Comment: So there is no FROM or there is? confused about this now.

Answer (score 0):

It exists in another table, not the table you are updating! What you are trying to do is update via join. Depending on the database you are using, the syntax varies.

For example, here is pseudo syntax:

```
Update products,   products_to_categories
Set products.products_status = 0
Where products.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id And
products_to_categories.categories_id = 114
```